# Given an input string of random letters find letters that make up numbers in Java

Tags: java

I am looking to write a program where I am given a string containing jumbled letters from several concatenated words. Each word is a number from zero to nine. Each number may be in the string multiple times. I need to write a program that returns integers corresponding to the letters in the string.

For example:

input: reuonnoinfe
output: 149

explanation: the given string has one, four and nine

what I have tried so far is:

```
    public static int strConv(String str) {
    HashMap<Character, Integer> charCount = new HashMap<>();
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        Integer count = charCount.get(c);
        if (count == null) count = 0;
        map.put(c, ++count);
    }
}
```

Note: If there are enough characters for multiple of the same numbers, I am expected to simply print the same number over again (ie. input: ooonneeto would be 112)

I am new to java so unsure how to proceed. I am adding all characters I see to a map. Not sure what the next step would be? How can I check if the characters I have in my map correlate to any numbers between 0 and 9?

Comment: Did you make an attempt? If so, provide it in a code block.

Comment: Your question is broad, needs focus and does not show any attempt that you tried it yourself. It is also unclear what exactly your struggling with. For example, do you already know how to write a Hello-World program? That is the first step to "get started". Or maybe are you struggling with setting up Java? It is currently impossible to answer your question. Downvoted and voting to close.

Comment: It is also unclear what "if these letters make any numbers" mean, I do not get at all why `reuonnoinfe` should yield `149`, we need a detailed explanation here.

Comment: reposted with better explanation and an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61923409/how-to-check-if-a-random-string-has-letters-that-make-up-numbers-in-java

Comment: @Zabuzard Presumably because it can be rearrange to spell "one four nine". Though it could also spell "one" twice.

Comment: @youngdev Don't repost. [Edit] the question to add clarification. And make sure to point out what you're specifically stuck on. We're not just going to do your homework for you.

Comment: edited. apologies for reposting

Comment: Voting to reopen, the question has improved significantly now.

Comment: This is a tough question, probably not that simple to solve. How should you proceed if there are multiple valid solutions? Is any solution enough?

Comment: Can others consider reopening? @shmosel

Comment: @Zabuzard basically if there are enough characters for multiple of the same numbers, I am expected to simply print the same number over again (ie. input: ooonneeto would be 112)

Comment: The only algorithm I can think of is 1) Sort the input string in alphabetical order. 2) In a for loop starting at zero and ending with some large number, create the string from the iterator and sort it in alphabetical order.  3) Break the loop when you get a match.  Not elegant, but should work.

Comment: Two additional thoughts.  ooonneeto is not 112.  owonneeto would be 112.  Second, you can limit the range of numbers you have to search by counting the letters in the input.  For example, if there are 16 letters in the input, the number has to be in between 10 to the 4th and 10 to the 6th.  The smallest number is 3 letters, the largest is 5 letters.  16 / 5 is 4 (ceiling) and 16 / 3 is 6 (ceiling).

Comment: @youngdev My question was more about if the text qualifies for two different numbers. For example if both `123` and `124` would be possible. This can be more likely the more numbers there are. Also, what about the order? `112` and `121` and `211` would be valid, Is any correct number enough or do you need to find all?

Comment: Can you have extra letters at the end? Something line "oneb" => "1"?

Answer (score 3):

The OP provided this question.

> I am given a string containing jumbled letters from several
>   concatenated words. Each word is a number from zero to nine. Each
>   (word) number may be in the string multiple times. I need to write a
>   program that returns integers corresponding to the letters in the
>   string.

It would be interesting to see where the question came from.  It's more complicated to solve than it appears at first glance.

Based on the text of the question and further comments made by the OP, we can also assume the following:

1. The input is guaranteed to be correct or resolvable.
2. The output will be an integer.
3. The digits of the output will always be in ascending order.  In other words 134, not 143 or 341.

Based on my earlier comments, I came up with a simple algorithm to solve this question.  It's not elegant, but it is simple.

1. Create a `String` array to hold the number words.

Here's a method to do that.

```
public String[] createWordList() {
    String[] numberWords = new String[10];
    numberWords[0] = "zero";
    numberWords[1] = "one";
    numberWords[2] = "two";
    numberWords[3] = "three";
    numberWords[4] = "four";
    numberWords[5] = "five";
    numberWords[6] = "six";
    numberWords[7] = "seven";
    numberWords[8] = "eight";
    numberWords[9] = "nine";
    return numberWords;
}
```

2. Sort the input `String` in alphabetical order.

Here's a 3 line method to do that.

```
public String sort(String input) {
    char[] digits = input.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(digits);
    return new String(digits);
}
```

3. Based on the number of letters in the input String, calculate the smallest and largest possible number.  Since the smallest number word is 3 characters and the largest number word is 5 characters, the minimum and maximum integer can be calculated like this.

Here's a method to do just that.

```
public int findNumber(String[] numberWords, String input) {
    input = sort(input);

    int length = input.length();
    double minPower = Math.floor(length / 5d);
    double maxPower = Math.ceil(length / 3d);
    int minimum = (int) Math.pow(10d, minPower);
    int maximum = (int) Math.pow(10d, maxPower);

    for (int index = minimum; index < maximum; index++) {
        String test = createNumberString(numberWords,
                index);
        test = sort(test);
        if (test.equals(input)) {
            return index;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Now, all that's left is to write the `createNumberString` method.

```
public String createNumberString(String[] numberWords,
        int index) {
    String output = "";

    while (index > 0) {
        int digit = index % 10;
        output = numberWords[digit] + output;
        index /= 10;
    }

    return output;
}
```

When I put these methods together and ran some tests, I got the following results.

```
reuonnoinfe --> 149
owonneeto --> 112
seveneightninetwothreefive --> 235789
```

There's also a recursive algorithm that would look at the input String and try the number words one at a time until all of the characters in the input were used.

Since this recursive algorithm involves back tracking, I haven't outlined it.  I leave that as an exercise for some Java developer more advanced than me.

I hope this has been helpful.  This problem is a bit complicated for a Java beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Gilbert that this problem is more complicated than it appears. Anyone solving this problem from scratch will take few hours. Moreover there are corner cases which can fail the tests. Below is the solution I wrote in C#. A Java solution should be very similar. To understand it will required deep diving into parsing jumbled letters, nested loops, if and do while conditions. Below are my steps to solve this problem. I am sure with more time, it can be made better.

1. Create a String array of numerals.
2. Loop through each character of each numeral in array and find out if these characters exist in the jumbled input string.
3. If all the characters of a numeral are found
   (a) Using the index of the found character in the jumbled
   string, remove one instance of characters of the numeral from the
   jumbled string.
   (b) add the numeral in a List of integer collection.
4. Repeat steps #2 & #3 until you can no longer find any more numerals in the jumbled string.
5. Sort the collection of List of found numbers.
6. Convert the List into a string output.

Below is the full code with some test written in the Main method.

```
            class NumeralProgram
{
    static readonly string[] numerals = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };

    static string FindNumbers(string input, string[] arrnumerals)
    {
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

        do
        {
            string startInput = input;
            foreach (string numeral in arrnumerals)
            {
                bool numeralFound = false;
                string storedInput = input;
                foreach (char cn in numeral)
                {
                    int count = input.Count(c => c == cn); // find char for numeral in input string

                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        numeralFound = true;
                        int index = input.IndexOf(cn);
                        input = input.Remove(index, 1); // remove char for the found numeral
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        numeralFound = false;
                        input = storedInput; // roll back to previous input
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (numeralFound)
                {
                    int number = Array.IndexOf(arrnumerals, numeral);
                    // Console.WriteLine(number);  // to view individual number during test

                    numbers.Add(number);
                }
            }

            if (startInput == input)  // stop when chars of numerals are not found
                break;

        } while (input.Length > 0);

        numbers.Sort();
        string output = String.Join("", numbers);
        return output;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        string input, output;

        input = "reuonnoinfe";
        output = FindNumbers(input, numerals);
        Console.WriteLine(output);

        input = "nzerinextneiootnrnoeneeeeuoeoheetehounzoiuetrhfefeezuivirfwieotgoottfnrnneghetserhrwsgesfherhtiitrerevreernhveofiouver";
        output = FindNumbers(input, numerals);
        Console.WriteLine(output);

        input = "tveiifogvweesotwnetnvfeheiotwo";
        output = FindNumbers(input, numerals);
        Console.WriteLine(output);

        input = "ugstrheone";
        output = FindNumbers(input, numerals);
        Console.WriteLine(output);

        input = "seoeisowufxrzohgiettrven";
        output = FindNumbers(input, numerals);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Python3 version of Neal Pandey C# code.

```py
def find_numbers(input):
        number_list = [ "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" ]
        numbers = []
        while len(input) > 0:
            startInput = input
            for  numeral in number_list:
                storedInput = input
                numeralFound = False
                for cn in numeral:
                    count = input.count(cn) 
                    if count > 0:
                        numeralFound = True
                        index = input.index(cn)
                        if len(input) > index:
                            input = input[:index:] + input[index+1::]
                    else:
                        numeralFound = False
                        input = storedInput
                        break
                if numeralFound :
                    number = number_list.index(numeral)
                    numbers.append(str(number))

            if startInput == input:
                break

        numbers.sort()
        output = "".join(numbers)
        return output


input = "reuonnoinfe"
output = find_numbers(input)
print(output)

input = "nzerinextneiootnrnoeneeeeuoeoheetehounzoiuetrhfefeezuivirfwieotgoottfnrnneghetserhrwsgesfherhtiitrerevreernhveofiouver"
output = find_numbers(input)
print(output)

input = "tveiifogvweesotwnetnvfeheiotwo"
output = find_numbers(input)
print(output)

input = "ugstrheone"
output = find_numbers(input)
print(output)

input = "seoeisowufxrzohgiettrven"
output = find_numbers(input)
print(output)
```

Output

```
reuonnoinfe ==> 149
nzerinextneiootnrnoeneeeeuoeoheetehounzoiuetrhfefeezuivirfwieotgoottfnrnneghetserhrwsgesfherhtiitrerevreernhveofiouver ==> 0001112233333444455677888999
tveiifogvweesotwnetnvfeheiotwo ==> 12225578
ugstrheone ==> 1
seoeisowufxrzohgiettrven ==> 01236
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package test;

public class B {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String a = "otwthreeoneotwthrezeroeofnievoetwthreeonotwthreeoneotwthrezeroeoneotwthreeotwthreeoneotwthrezeroeoneotwthreeoneonee";
        String[] words = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
        String finalString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            String w = words[i];
            while (true) {
                if (hasWord(w, a)) {
                    a = removeWord(w, a);
                    finalString += i;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        System.out.println(finalString);

    }

    private static boolean hasWord(String word, String input) {
        for (char w : word.toCharArray()) {
            if (input.indexOf(w) != -1) {
                input = input.replaceFirst(w + "", "");
            } else
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static String removeWord(String word, String input) {

        for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
            input = input.replaceFirst(c + "", "");
        }

        return input;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s = "twosixfourzerothreezeronineonetwothreefourfivesixseveneightninefive";
    
    String[] str = { "zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};
    // z o w h u v x s g
    String result = "";
    String d="";
    
    char resultc = 0;
    String nresult = "";
    
    char[] sc = s.toCharArray();
    
    int counter = 0;
    int slength = s.length();
    
    do {
        try {
            if(s.contains("z")) {

                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('z'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('e'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('r'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('o'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                nresult = nresult+0;
                System.out.println("SOriginal: "+s);
                System.out.println("nResult: "+nresult);
                
            }else if(s.contains("w")) {
                
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('t'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('w'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('o'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                nresult = nresult+2;
                System.out.println("SOriginal: "+s);
                System.out.println("nResult: "+nresult);
            }else if(s.contains("u")) {
                
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('f'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('o'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('u'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('r'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                nresult = nresult+4;
                System.out.println("SOriginal: "+s);
                System.out.println("nResult: "+nresult);
            }else if(s.contains("x")) {
                
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('s'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('i'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('x'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                nresult = nresult+6;
                System.out.println("SOriginal: "+s);
                System.out.println("nResult: "+nresult);
            }else if(s.contains("g")) {
                
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('e'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('i'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('g'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('h'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('t'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                nresult = nresult+8;
                System.out.println("SOriginal: "+s);
                System.out.println("nResult: "+nresult);
            }else if(s.contains("h")) {
                
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('t'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('h'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('r'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('e'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('e'), "");
                counter=counter+1;

                nresult = nresult+3;
                System.out.println("SOriginal: "+s);
                System.out.println("nResult: "+nresult);
            }else if(s.contains("o") && s.contains("n") && s.contains("e")) {
                
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('o'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('n'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('e'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                nresult = nresult+1;
                System.out.println("SOriginal: "+s);
                System.out.println("nResult: "+nresult);
            }else if(s.contains("f") && s.contains("i") && s.contains("v") && s.contains("e")) {
                
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('f'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('i'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('v'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('e'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                nresult = nresult+5;
                System.out.println("SOriginal: "+s);
                System.out.println("nResult: "+nresult);
            }else if(s.contains("s") && s.contains("e") && s.contains("v") && s.contains("e") && s.contains("n")) {
                
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('s'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('e'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('v'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('e'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('n'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                nresult = nresult+7;
                System.out.println("SOriginal: "+s);
                System.out.println("nResult: "+nresult);
            }else if(s.contains("n") && s.contains("i") && s.contains("n") && s.contains("e")) {
                
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('n'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('i'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('n'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                s=s.replaceFirst(Character.toString('e'), "");
                counter=counter+1;
                nresult = nresult+9;
                System.out.println("SOriginal: "+s);
                System.out.println("nResult: "+nresult);
            }else {
                break;
            }

        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid String "+e.getMessage());
        }
        
    }while(!(counter==slength));
    
    System.out.println("Result: "+nresult);
    
    if(s.length()!=0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid String");
    }else {
    char[] st = nresult.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(st);
    System.out.println(st);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Looking back at Bala's output above:*

**ugstrheone ==> 1**
This string is not valid for input.  A g is present but eight cannot be spelled.  S is present but six and seven cannot be spelled.

**seoeisowufxrzohgiettrven ==> 01236**
This is 024678 eeeefghiinooorrssttuvwxz when it's sorted.

The u and g indicate that four and eight are present.  There is one x, but two s’s, so a seven is present.
01236 is eeeehinooorrsttwxz

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;

public class DigitsFromString {
    public static LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> evenMapping;
    public static LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> oddMapping;
    public static LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> in;
    public static LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> counter = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public static void init() {
        //unique characters in even number
        evenMapping = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        evenMapping.put("z", 0);
        evenMapping.put("w", 2);
        evenMapping.put("u", 4);
        evenMapping.put("x", 6);
        evenMapping.put("g", 8);

        //unique characters in odd number after even unique characters are removed
        oddMapping = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        oddMapping.put("o", 1);
        oddMapping.put("t", 3);
        oddMapping.put("f", 5);
        oddMapping.put("s", 7);

        //digits in words
        in = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        in.put(0, "zero");
        in.put(1, "one");
        in.put(2, "two");
        in.put(3, "three");
        in.put(4, "four");
        in.put(5, "five");
        in.put(6, "six");
        in.put(7, "seven");
        in.put(8, "eight");
        in.put(9, "nine");
    }

    public static String sort(String input) {
        char[] digits = input.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(digits);
        return new String(digits);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DigitsFromString permutations = new DigitsFromString();

        
        List<String> inputs = new ArrayList<>();
        inputs.add("reuonnoinfe");
        inputs.add("eightfourone");
        inputs.add("tveiifogvweesotwnetnvfeheiotwo");
        inputs.add("seoeisowufxrzohgiettrventhgieghteitegih");
        inputs.add("nzerinextneiootnrnoeneeeeuoeoheetehounzoiuetrhfefeezuivirfwieotgoottfnrnneghetserhrwsgesfherhtiitrerevreernhveofiouvernzerinextneiootnrnoeneeeeuoeoheetehounzoiuetrhfefeezuivirfwieotgoottfnrnneghetserhrwsgesfherhtiitrerevreernhveofiouver");
        even:
        for (String input : inputs) {

            counter = new LinkedHashMap<>();

            char[] digits = input.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(digits);

            init();


            for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
                if (counter.get(Character.toString(digits[i])) != null) {
                    counter.put(Character.toString(digits[i]), counter.get(Character.toString(digits[i])) + 1);
                } else {
                    counter.put(Character.toString(digits[i]), 1);
                }
            }

            String res = "";

            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> map : evenMapping.entrySet()) {
                if (counter.get(map.getKey()) != null) {
                    int cnt = counter.get(map.getKey());

                    if (cnt != 0) {
                        String digitStr = in.get(map.getValue());
                        char[] tmp = digitStr.toCharArray();
                        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
                            for (int k = 0; k < tmp.length; k++) {
                                if (counter.get(Character.toString(tmp[k])) == null) {
                                    System.out.println("Invalid String");
                                    continue even;
                                }
                            }
                            res = res + map.getValue();

                            for (int j = 0; j < tmp.length; j++) {
                                if (counter.get(Character.toString(tmp[j])) != null) {
                                    counter.put(Character.toString(tmp[j]), counter.get(Character.toString(tmp[j])) - 1);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> map : oddMapping.entrySet()) {
                if (counter.get(map.getKey()) != null) {
                    int cnt = counter.get(map.getKey());

                    if (cnt != 0) {
                        String digitStr = in.get(map.getValue());
                        char[] tmp = digitStr.toCharArray();
                        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {

                            for (int k = 0; k < tmp.length; k++) {
                                if (counter.get(Character.toString(tmp[k])) == null) {
                                    System.out.println("Invalid String");
                                    continue even;
                                }
                            }
                            res = res + map.getValue();

                            for (int j = 0; j < tmp.length; j++) {
                                if (counter.get(Character.toString(tmp[j])) != null) {
                                    counter.put(Character.toString(tmp[j]), counter.get(Character.toString(tmp[j])) - 1);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //splcase -- 9
            if (counter.get("i") != null) {
                int cnt = counter.get("i");

                if (cnt != 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
                        res = res + "9";
                    }
                }
            }
            res = sort(res);
            System.out.println(res);
        }

    }
}
```